# pow() function in c is getting me wrong results

Tags: c++, c

I'm trying to convert an 8 bit array into into a number from 0-255 by adding values depending on the position in the field.

if I use

```
int array[8]={
            0,1,1,0,0,0,0,1
    };
    int *p = array;
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i<8; i++){
        if(p[i]!=0){
            a = pow(2,i);
            printf("%i\n",a);
        }
    };
```

I get:

```
2
4
128
```

as results, which would be right so far. 
but if I use

```
int array[8]={
            0,1,1,0,0,0,0,1
    };
    int *p = array;
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i<8; i++){
        if(p[i]!=0){
            a = a + pow(2,i);
            printf("%i\n",a);
        }
    };
```

I instead get:

```
2686758
2686762
2686890
```

when I expect:

```
134
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It smells like use of uninitialized variable `a`. Can't be certain without a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Yeah.. down and close vote for showing code, but not showing data.  We don't even know what type 'a' is;(

Comment: if `array[0]` the MSB - i.e 128 or 1?

Answer (score 3):

You have not initialised `a` to 0.

The following should work

```
int array[8]={
        0,1,1,0,0,0,0,1
};
int *p = array;
int i;
a = 0                     // << Initialise a
for (i = 0; i<8; i++){
    if(p[i]!=0){
        a = a + pow(2,i);
        printf("%i\n",a);
    }
};
```

You always need to provide an initial value for your variables. Otherwise, you can expect them to start with ANY value.

In the second piece of code you are accumulating `a=a+pow(2,i)` and it is here where the first time `a` is used, it will contain some undetermined value.

Comment: Why are you using `pow` - an expensive function in this context

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the statement: `a = a + pow(2,1);`
`a` has indeterminate value because it has not been initialized and you are using it in arithmetic operation.

Answer (score 1):

`pow` is intended to compute the exponential function of two real (not integer) values. So you could use it to compute π<sup>3/2</sup>. It is really not ideal for computing integer powers of 2. Much simpler and faster (though possibly less readable until you get used to it) is to write 2<sup>i</sup> as `(1UL << i)`. However, in this particular case you don't need either of those. You could just do the following:

```
int a = 0;
for (int index = 0, value = 1; index < 8; ++index, value *= 2)
  if (p[i]) a += value;
```

or even more directly

```
int a = 0;
for (int value = 1, *p = array; value < 256; value *= 2, ++p)
  if (*p) a += value;
```

(As has been mentioned, the problem in your original was not actually the use of `pow` but rather the absence of the initialization `int a = 0`.)

Answer (score -1):

alright ! i fixed it by adding `=0;` to the `int a;`intitialization
Tanks !

Comment: If you found the answers useful, would you mind accepting one?